# Chosen select is not applied when I add rows based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

```
`<script>
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();

    $('#example-4').on('click', '.ui-data-table-delete', function() {
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        delete_row(rowIndex);
    });

// Delegate the input event to the table body
$('#example-4').on('input', 'tr:last input', function() {
    // Check if all fields in the last row are filled
    var isRowFilled = true;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isRowFilled = false;

            return false; // Exit the loop early if any field is empty
        }
    });

    // If all fields are filled, trigger the add_row function
    if (isRowFilled) {

        add_row();
    }
});


   
});

function add_row() {

    var table = document.getElementById("example-4");
    var t1 = table.rows.length;

    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.textContent = t1;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

    cell4.className = 'abc';
    cell3.className = 'abc';
    // chzn-select

    var select = $('<select class="chzn-select" style="width:200px" name="item[' + t1 + ']"></select>');
    <?php foreach ($item_data as $value):?>
    select.append('<option value="<?= $value->PKItemID; ?>"><?= $value->ItemName; ?></option>');
    <?php endforeach;?>
    select.appendTo(cell2);
    select.chosen();

    $('<input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="number" min="1" name="qty['+t1+']">').appendTo(cell3);
    $('<input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="manufactureID['+t1+']">').appendTo(cell4);
    $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ui-data-table-delete"><i class="feather icon-trash"></i></a>').appendTo(cell5);
 
}

function delete_row(rowIndex) {
    var table = document.getElementById("example-4");
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < table.rows.length) {
        table.deleteRow(rowIndex);
        // (rowIndex < table.rows.length) , Yeah well this ensures that 
        // the header row is not deleted.
        // Adjust index numbers after deleting row
        for (var i = rowIndex; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent = i; 
            // The hidden index is maintained well by the in 
            // built deleteRow function.
            // We are just making the visible index and the hidden 
            // the same.
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid row index:', rowIndex);
    }


}
</script>
```

The chosen select is fine when I don't include the add row functionality based on whether the last row is filled or not. But when I include it chosen is not working. The other thing I noticed that sometimes chosen is applied but then add row based on user input doesn't work. I do have a separate add_row button to add rows.

I tried using select2 library but it is messing with the css of the template.